# How To Create Database Index Without Waiting To Complete

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, azure-functions

I'm using Azure Functions to insert lots of data into a SQL Server database once per month but at the same time I want to create an index on one of the tables.

Is it possible to kick off the create index and have it run until complete without it tying up the rest of the function.

In other words can the function complete and the index carries on building in the background?

Thanks

Comment: No this isn't really possible. The index `CREATE` needs to run in a session. There is no way to offload this to a system task. The connection that kicks it off needs to be open until it completes so the Azure function can't exit as that will kill the connection

Comment: @Larnu - offline/online isn't synch/asynch

Comment: Thanks for your reply - what's best practice then with say creating an index on a table with a million rows in it - I have read creating the index first before inserting the data is a bad idea but thats the only way I can see to do it.

Comment: it will not take much time to index a million rows. just let system do it automatically.

Comment: The SSMS is multi-threaded so as long as the Insert and Create Index is not accessing the same data it is possible to do the two in parallel.  if the two operations are accessing the same data then the Index will not contain all the entries when completed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason not to create the index first is that it slows down the write, but this is not true 100% of the time. If you are inserting the data in the same order as the index, then creating the index first may not be a bad thing as the index wouldn't have to adjust much as you go along. You would need to test each scenario to see which is the best choice for your specific situation.

As jdweng mentioned creating the index at the same time as the data does not solve the problem of creating the index first, as it introduces competing locks and if the index is completed first it will need to be updated every row just like if you had created it first.

Some process will need to stay alive to complete the index, but it doesn't have to be that function. Once the insert completes you could have the function call another process for creating the index. There are a lot of options for this including another Function, a Logic App (by calling a stored proc), or the SQL Job agent if that is available to you.